# Create a new file in maven resource folder

Tags: java, maven

```
this.getClass().getResource("file path")
```

I know this will access the file in maven's resource folder.

But how can I create a new file in maven resource folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't for the simple reason that the classpath can be mapped to a URL or a JAR file and there is no way to "create" a resource inside an already existing JAR or a remote URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the class file for the given class won't be loaded from a JAR file when its code executes, you can use something like this:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource(filename).toURI());
file.createNewFile();
```

This pattern can be useful in unit test code, which typically executes before any class files are packed into a jar.

Note that you may need to wrap this in a try-catch block, because the `URL.toURI()` method may throw a URISyntaxException. However, for test code, you might just want to add a `throws` clause to the method declaration.